# how to create canvas in content document from firefox extension?

Tags: canvas, firefox-addon

I'm developing a firefox extension, so that i can create canvas elements in the content document (webpage loaded in the browser) from the extension.

My function is below:

```
function createCanvas(el, e, count)
{
    try{
    alert("create canvas");
    var x = getImgOffset(el).left;
    var y = getImgOffset(el).top;
    var body = window.content.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    //removeSelection();
    var canvas = {};
    canvas.node = window.content.document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
    canvas.node.setAttribute('id','canvas');
    canvas.node.setAttribute('height',el.offsetHeight+'px');
    canvas.node.setAttribute('width',el.offsetWidth+'px');
    canvas.node.setAttribute('style','left:'+x+';top:'+y+';border: 1px solid grey; position:absolute; z-index:2;');
    body.appendChild(canvas.node);
    alert("d");
    canvas.node.onmouseover = function(event){ 
        var t = (event && event.target) || (event && event.srcElement); 
        //alert("d : "+t.tagName);
        initCanvas(event);
    }
    initCanvas(e);
    }catch(er)
    {
        alert("crt canvas : "+er.name+"\n"+er.message);
    }
}
```

This code is working when I call the function from inside the webpage. But, it is throwing an exception when I tried to call this function `createCanvas` from the toolbar.

I'm getting error in the following line:

```
canvas.node = window.content.document.createElement('canvas');
```

I've tried the following lines also:

```
canvas.node = window.content.document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'canvas');
```

&

```
canvas.node = window.content.document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html:canvas');
```

But still getting the same error:

```
Error Name:  NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE
Error Message: Component is not available
```

Please help me in this issue.

Comment: It's often easiest to learn by example, and a good example of an extension that uses canvases is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-preview/

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add an html:canvas element in your overlay.xul:

```
    <html:canvas id="my-canvas" style="display: none;" />
```

and then reference it by id in your javascript:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
```

I've [blogged about how to use canvas elements to let browser extensions take screenshots](http://blog.webmynd.com/2011/06/07/how-to-create-a-browser-extension-that-records-screenshots/).

Comment: I need to create `canvas` elements inside the webpage from the toolbar.

I'm getting error there.

Comment: I'm not sure why there is a problem adding the canvas element into the page from the add-on code, but one approach you could try is embedding a <script> into the page that creates and embeds the canvas element. Testing on the Firefox 4 web console shows it's perfectly fine to do document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas'));

Comment: Thank you @AmirNathoo . This worked for me. I don't find the logic actually.

Thanks anyhow.